# Tomcat DataSource - Connection Pooling

Tags: java, spring, apache, tomcat, connection-pooling

I am using tomcat datasource connection pool for my app. I have set the max number of connections to 20. I am running 5 concurrent requests at a time. However some  of my calls are timing out because no available connection is found. How long does it take for a connection to get back to the pool once is completed? Are there any properties that would help with this?

I was looking at different attributes in this [link](http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/tomcat-jdbc-connection-pool-configuration-for-production-and-development/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default connection timeout 60sec.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource;
import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PoolProperties;

public class SimplePOJOExample {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      PoolProperties p = new PoolProperties();
      p.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql");
      p.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      p.setUsername("root");
      p.setPassword("password");
      p.setJmxEnabled(true);
      p.setTestWhileIdle(false);
      p.setTestOnBorrow(true);
      p.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1");
      p.setTestOnReturn(false);
      p.setValidationInterval(30000);
      p.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(30000);
      p.setMaxActive(100);
      p.setInitialSize(10);
      p.setMaxWait(10000);
      p.setRemoveAbandonedTimeout(60);
      p.setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(30000);
      p.setMinIdle(10);
      p.setLogAbandoned(true);
      p.setRemoveAbandoned(true);
      p.setJdbcInterceptors(
        "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;"+
        "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer");
      DataSource datasource = new DataSource();
      datasource.setPoolProperties(p);

      Connection con = null;
      try {
        con = datasource.getConnection();
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from user");
        int cnt = 1;
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println((cnt++)+". Host:" +rs.getString("Host")+
              " User:"+rs.getString("User")+" Password:"+rs.getString("Password"));
        }
        rs.close();
        st.close();
      } finally {
        if (con!=null) try {con.close();}catch (Exception ignore) {}
      }
  }

}
```

And here is an example on how to configure a resource for JNDI lookups

```
<Resource name="jdbc/TestDB"
      auth="Container"
      type="javax.sql.DataSource"
      factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
      testWhileIdle="true"
      testOnBorrow="true"
      testOnReturn="false"
      validationQuery="SELECT 1"
      validationInterval="30000"
      timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="30000"
      maxActive="100"
      minIdle="10"
      maxWait="10000"
      initialSize="10"
      removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
      removeAbandoned="true"
      logAbandoned="true"
      minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="30000"
      jmxEnabled="true"
      jdbcInterceptors="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;
        org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer"
      username="root"
      password="password"
      driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
      url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql"/>
```

If you find any more difficulty refer this
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html

Comment: Thanks @Bhaskara Arani. After a DB operation is performed will it take 60 seconds for the connection to get back to the pool? Can you please help point out the parameter as well?

Comment: Here itself all parameters are mentioned, which parameters are you want extra  p.setMaxActive(100);

Comment: or  refer this http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html

Comment: Thanks Bhaskara, After a DB operation is performed will it take 60 seconds for the connection to get back to the pool?

Comment: No, its depend upon how much much you open the connection, after connection close it will come to pool